# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

I want to generate a JAR but every time I get this error:

**Console log**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.160 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-27T00:37:06+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)
        on project qengine: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 9 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionExceptions
```

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>napd</groupId>
    <artifactId>qengine</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>rdf4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdf4j-client</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jena</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- <plugin> <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> <version>3.8.1</version> 
                <configuration> <source>8</source> <target>8</target> </configuration> </plugin> 
                <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <archive> <manifest> <mainClass>qengine.Main</mainClass> 
                </manifest> </archive> </configuration> </plugin> -->
        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allJars</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <source>9</source> <target>9</target> </configuration> </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The first thing is you should upgrade the maven-compiler-plugin to most recent versions. Second the error message looks like you don't use a JDK9+ it looks more like use jdk less than 9....

Comment: hi @khmarbaise ,thank you for your return,I corrected the plugin and pointed the java_home to the correct jdk. Now I can generate he JAR but I still have a problem to execute it

Comment: And which problems?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Is the `JAVA_HOME` variable configured to the JDK 9 path?

(2) Try replacing the `configuration` for `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <fork>true</fork>
  <executable>javac9</executable>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `JAVA_HOME' isn't configured for JDK 9 `,i tried to change the configuration section but i keep having error  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project qengine: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]

Comment: There is no _JDK 1.9_, it's [JDK 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/index.html). And what's the point of this with [a maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 version that's 8(!) years old](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin)?

Comment: @SilverMoon _khmarbaise_
 gave you a hint in a comment to your question 7(!) hours before you commented here. Apparently you didn't consider that. Are you really looking for help here?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Brings up a good point. It may be a compatibility issue for the older version of `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Comment: Note: You need a minimum of 3.6.1 for JDK 9 module support.